# Is the weighted search option working properly in Fuse.js?

Tags: fuse.js

I'm using Fuse.js on a project and trying to get some behavior working have i'm finding the results given out by Fuse to be confusing.

For reference i'm using these options to initialize Fuse:

```
includeMatches: true,
shouldSort: true,
includeScore: true,
threshold: 0.2,
distance: 100,
maxPatternLength: 32,
minMatchCharLength: 1,
keys: [
  { name: 'name', weight: 1 },
  { name: 'description', weight: 0.25 },
  { name: 'tags', weight: 0.1 },
  { name: 'other', weight: 0.05 },
]
```

And when i'm searching for "asian" for example I get these results:

```
Nice Restaurant by the Sea
Score: 0.00095 
Matched by:
tags -> Asian

Sweet Lao Restaurant
Score: 0.00095 
Matched by:
tags -> Asian

Oriental Cuisine
Score: 0.00095 
Matched by:
description -> Maybe the best Asian restaurant in the world!
tags -> Asian

Sushi Asian Fusion Grill
Score: 0.00095 
Matched by:
name -> Sushi Asian Fusion Grill
tags -> Asian
```

Now to my understanding, when i put the weight of the "name" key at 1 (the maximum) i would expect it to match the **Sushi Asian Fusion Grill** first or rank it higher than the others since the name should be the higher influencer of the score, but it appears that the score it gives to all of them is basically the same, whether or not it matches with only the tags or both the name and the tags.

Is this intended behavior? How can i make it so that if it finds it in the name it ranks it higher?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First is that you want the match to ignore the location (e.g. search for 'Asian' anywhere in the title) and second you don't want it to lower the weight of title because it's long (ignoreFieldNorm).

Add these to the options:

```
{
    ignoreLocation: true,
    ignoreFieldNorm: true, // Don't weight a short field higher than a long one
}
```